# Is WordPress secure with 757 & 646 permissions?

Tags: wordpress, plesk, parallels

We have a Plesk 12.0.18 on Centos Server, when a client installed with the wizard a Wordpress from de panel, it deploy fine the wordpress, but the directories have a 757 permissions and files 646. That's secure ?? it's correct?

If i change the permissions to 755 (directories) and 644 (files), the wordpress don't works correctly (Can't upload medias, themes, can't edit files online...)

Thx!!.

Comment: That sometimes indicates incorrect directory/file ownership.

Comment: 'the wordpress don't works correctly.' <- Can you please expand on this point?

Comment: I found the following article to fix the permissions to 757 & 646: http://kb.odin.com/en/121511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> directories have a 757 permissions and files 646.
>
> That's secure ??

No, it's not secure.

> it's correct?

Yes, it's correct for mod_php(Apache Module) PHP handler.

> Can't upload medias, themes, can't edit files online

Change you subscription/domains PHP handler to FastCGI.

If your Plesk's license key provides [WordPress ToolKit](http://www.odin.com/products/plesk/wordpress-toolkit/) you can use it to secure WordPress installation:

[image]

Comment: Great Work!  I solve my issue with this answer. I had Apache Module enabled.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress: Recommended File & Folder Permissions

- Root directory           0755
- wp-admin         0755
- wp-content           0755
- wp-includes          0755
- .htaccess            0640
- readme.html          0400
- wp-config.php            0644
- wp-admin/index.php       0644.
- wp-admin/.htaccess       0640

Via: http://orangecopper.com/blog/recommended-file-and-folder-permissions-for-your-wordpress-blog-installation